# Altering linking arrow width in QGIS EasyCustomLabeling plugin

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to alter the thickness of the line linking the label to the symbol, which is generated using the QGIS EasyCustomLabeling plugin?  I would like to make the line thinner.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

**Properties/Style/Simple line** of the layer named "label..." : u can define any style u want ... i think u can even make it label-dependent using variables ...